# Nested and not nested routing with Stencil.js router

Tags: routes, navigation, stenciljs

I want to implement a web application with tabs and a toolbar, at the bottom and at the top of the page, respectively.

1. I think in all the pages with tab bar the tab bar should be the same one, I mean the same code. And also the toolbar of those may be the same one, as well.
2. There will be buttons on the toolbar, when clicked there will be a whole page view without the tabs, but with a toolbar again with a back button and few other buttons. this toolbar may be a different one, I am ok with that.
3. The entry point route `'/'` should show the first tab's page as if it is clicked.

The problem is I cannot manage to have all those properly:

When I get one I loose the other. When I get a shared tab bar and a main toolbar, I can still have 2 since I do not nest this view's route in the tab views', however, I loose 3 and it shows an empty page not the one with first tab's since to share the tab bar and the main toolbar I nest the tab views inside another route's view that has the shared tab bar and the toolbar.

When I do not nest the tab bar routes inside a route, I loose sharing the tab bar and the toolbar. And also I get the tab bar where I do not want to get, inside the pages navigated from the main toolbar.

I am using the Stencil.js compiler and its router add-on in my project. I cannot use the new Ionic (verison 4) since it is beta yet and not clear how to use with navigation to me.

Those problems seems like arousing from the fact that the router nests the routes with route elements' url attributes not with nesting the route elements.

How to handle a proper navigation pattern for a web app with a shared tab bar, a  toolbar and views without those getting whole screen itself?

Comment: hi can you please share your code base for implementation of routing ?